# How to use Swagger with Github?

Tags: java, spring, github, swagger

I was creating a yml file through the Swagger page, and everything is showing up correctly:

[image]

When I push the changes to github, I hope to see them the same way, but I see the following:

[image]

I don't know if I'm missing some configuration or something in the project. This **project** is a **Spring project**, with **Java 11**, and the dependency I'm using to comment on the project is the following:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

The path of the yml file is the **resources** folder.

Comment: Did you expect to see the Swagger UI interactive doc page inside GitHub? (The part that's on the right side of the editor.)

Comment: Yes, I would like to see that

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/swagger-ui-action
Or: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/swagger-ui